# How to get my input line(from file) into the right variables - name, quantity and ':' between them

Tags: c

Im building binnary tree and my input is :  <name_product>: <quantity<
if valid
and
<product_name>: <quantity< blallla..
if invalid

the names of products can have spaces between for example
Dell Xps Zt15: 20
Lenovo Wana8Banna: 10
Mac ProPeanuts: 1

so what I tried to do is creating char array(string) that I called checker to check if "blallla" is blank or not

also I have problem to get the name because %s get the string until space so I have problem to get Dell Xps Zt15 for example into the name

```
while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH,f)  )
  {
   sscanf(line,"%s: %d %s",name,&quantity,checker);
    if (checker[0]!='\0')
    {
      fprintf(stderr, ERROR INVALID_LINE);
    }
    if (checker[0]=='\0')
    {
      root=add_product (root, name, quantity);
    }
```

Comment: what is this? "%[^:]

Comment: thanks, I used strchr  and it worked
but I would like to understand the %[^:]  as well. can I take  %[^:]  and put it into string?